# How to make the link between 2 tables?

Tags: sql

I cannot make a link between my 'members' table and 'bookings'. I want to make the link between these 2 tables to display the user reservations thanks to an sql query :

[Display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zx2aM.png)

**I tried but my "user_id" field is not linked :**

[user](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rufW5.png)

[bookings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XYSRU.png)

I don't know how to link the 2 tables

Comment: Check out `JOIN`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User_id field is connecting both of you tables. You can use inner join have all the bookings and it's corresponding member details as below:

```
select m.user_id,m.pseudo, m.mail,b.name,b.date,b.timeslot, 
b.adresse,b.telephone,b.ville
from booking b inner join member m 
on b.member_id=m.member_id
```

Comment: I think my tables are not connected

Comment: Then user_id needs to be inserted in booking table with each booking to make a link between two tables. Do you have any other table which can connect these two tables?

Comment: but user_id is already in the bookings table but there is no link there

Comment: I don't know how to make the link

Comment: do you see what i mean ?